# How to implement click-to-share in telegram mini app?

Tags: telegram

I saw a telegram mini app with a sharing button. After clicking, It will jump to my chat list and I can select a chat, and the content in the input box is pasted.
There is an interface for forwarding messages on the official website, but it seems to be forwarding to a specific person, not jumping to the chat list to share.
so, what can I do to implement this feature? Thanks very much.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.